# Convert a datetime() record to date in c# for importation into VFP database

Tags: c#, excel, date, datetime, visual-foxpro

I'm currently building a data export/import tool for pulling data into a Visual Fox Pro database from an excel or CSV document.

I believe the code to be functional, however upon execution I recieve a data type mismatch error.

After some investigation I've notice a difference between the format of the dates I'm pulling and the field I'm pushing to.

The Fox pro database is set up to take Date records, however the data i'm trying to push is in date time format (the original record is date) but as far as I'm aware c# can only natively do datetime conversion.

The code getting the date from excel is as such:

```
importCommand.Parameters["TENSDATE"].Value = exportReader.IsDBNull(0)
     ? (object) DBNull.Value
     : DateTime.Parse(exportReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

Now, I've seen a lot of people use something like:

```
exportReader.GetValue(0).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

However I can't seem to get this functioning. Can someone advise me on the best way to achieve my goal.

Comment: Date-typed values have no format. Doesn't FoxPro have a `date` or `datetime` field type? Storing dates as strings is a very serious bug. What is the type of `TENSDATE`? Also note that `GetValue` returns anything as `object`. If the value is a string, you have to parse it first. If it's a double, it may be an OADate that wasn't converted by the provider. You can convert it with `DateTime.FromOADate(double)`

Comment: Who is using VFP today? It's 2017!

Comment: @silkfire, Is using VFP constrained by year? It is like asking who is using Fortran today (still the fastest language probably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply the type of the field when adding it to parameters. In this specific case, `OdbcType.DateTime` for a date field.

```
importCommand.Parameters.Add("@TENSDATE", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = exportReader.IsDBNull(0)
     ? (object) DBNull.Value
     : DateTime.Parse(exportReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

Comment: Hi mate, this solved that particular issue. Still got Data type mismatches, but I'll sort them in due course.

Comment: What did it really solve? You created a non-existant problem to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse dates which are in specific format you should use `DateTime.TryParseExact` method. You'll be able to pass specific format as an argument. Please refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

(Joshua Cameron-Macintosh, please close your open threads)

Despite my prior warnings, you are trying to do that the hard way, be it. VFP is a good data centric language and is clever enough to put a DateTime value into a Date or DateTime field. It is also clever enough to parse text values that denote a Date(time) - in the case of text, just like any other database or non-database parsers it does the parsing with given rules (such as using common canonical ODBC format of yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss with no problem, or if instructed to use a format of say DMY, it knows 1/2/2000 means Feb 1st,2000 etc.). In summary here the problem is not on VFP side at all. If you use CSV, then be sure you are using ODBC canonical format for dates (same goes on with SQL Server for example). In case of Excel file, provided you have the correct data types, you can directly transfer with no additional work, particularly that DBNull trial was totally unnecessary, VFP knows DbNull.Value already.

Anyway code always talks better. 
For this sample assume you have an excel file (d:\temp\ExcelImportData.xlsx) with SampleSheet sheet where you have the data columns as:

```
Customer ID: string
Order ID: integer
Ordered On: DateTime && where time parts were insignificant fro demo purposes
Shipped On: DateTime && Has NULL values
```

(You can build such a sample sheet using Northwind sample database's Orders table)

There is a VFP table (d:\temp\SampleImport.dbf) as the receiver where column information is:

```
CustomerId: Char(10) NOT NULL
OrderID: Int NOT NULL
OrderDate: Date NOT NULL
ShippedOn: DateTime NULL
```

Here is the simple read/write using a reader:

```
void Main()
{
    var vfpConnection = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=D:\temp";
    var xlsFileName = @"D:\temp\ExcelImportData.xlsx";
    var xlsConnection = $@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={xlsFileName};" +
    "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes\"";
    var xlsTableName = "SampleSheet$";
    using (var xlsCon = new OleDbConnection(xlsConnection))
    using (var vfpCon = new OleDbConnection(vfpConnection))
    {
        var cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand(@"insert into SampleImport
        (CustomerId, OrderId, OrderDate, ShippedOn)
        values
        (?,?,?,?)", vfpCon);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("customerId", OleDbType.WChar);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("orderId", OleDbType.Integer);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("orderDate", OleDbType.Date);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("shippedOn", OleDbType.Date);

        var readXl = new OleDbCommand($"select * from [{xlsTableName}]", xlsCon);
        xlsCon.Open();
        vfpCon.Open();
        var xlReader = readXl.ExecuteReader();
        while (xlReader.Read())
        {
            cmdInsert.Parameters["customerId"].Value = xlReader["Customer ID"];
            cmdInsert.Parameters["orderId"   ].Value = xlReader["Order ID"];
            cmdInsert.Parameters["orderDate" ].Value = xlReader["Ordered On"];
            cmdInsert.Parameters["shippedOn" ].Value = xlReader["Shipped On"];
            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        xlsCon.Close();
        vfpCon.Close();
    }
}
```